# HTML table and XsltForms

Tags: xforms, xsltforms

This example in the XForms wikibook that I modeled my code on, does not work as the repeated rows do not display.

http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/XForms/Repeat_into_table

Comment: Whether it works would depend mostly on [web browser support](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XForms), and xforms doesn't seem to be supported by any major browser

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XSLTForms does not support XForms repeat attributes but XForms repeat elements which can also be used with HTML tables. Implementing them should not be difficult, users did not yet ask for them actually!

Comment: Hello Alain, Just to clarify you mean that using xform repeat within tables is something that can be implemented in the future if it is asked for?

Comment: Sure! Repeat attributes have just a shorter syntax for authors to use repeat with HTML tables.

Answer (score 1):

Old post I know - but based on the response from Alain Couthures above, I made the changes necessary to the original XML to make it work with [XSLTForms](http://www.agencexml.com/xsltforms).
(I also removed the line regarding 'formfaces.js' , as per the comment in the original file).

```
<?xml-stylesheet href="xsltforms/xsltforms.xsl" type="text/xsl"?>
<?xsltforms-options debug="yes"?>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:xf="http://www.w3.org/2002/xforms">
       <head>
          <xf:model>
             <xf:instance xmlns="">
                <Data xmlns="">
                   <Person>
                      <PersonFullName>John Doe</PersonFullName>
                      <ContactTelephoneID>(555) 123-4567</ContactTelephoneID>
                   </Person>
                   <Person>
                      <PersonFullName>Jane Smith</PersonFullName>
                      <ContactTelephoneID>(555) 123-4567</ContactTelephoneID>
                   </Person>
                   <Person>
                      <PersonFullName>Jack Jones</PersonFullName>
                      <ContactTelephoneID>(555) 123-4567</ContactTelephoneID>
                   </Person>
                   <Person>
                      <PersonFullName>Sue Smith</PersonFullName>
                      <ContactTelephoneID>(555) 123-4567</ContactTelephoneID>
                   </Person>
                </Data>
             </xf:instance>
          </xf:model>
       </head>
       <body>
          <table border="1">
             <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Telephone Number</th>
             </tr>
             <tbody> 
                <xf:repeat id="persons" nodeset="Person">
                    <tr>
                        <td><xf:output ref="PersonFullName" /></td>
                        <td><xf:output ref="ContactTelephoneID" /></td>
                    </tr>
                </xf:repeat>
             </tbody>
          </table>
       </body>
    </html>
```

If you put this behind a web-server as (say) rep.xml, then it will render as a table with http://localhost:8080/rep.xml[image]

Couple of ways of bringing up a test HTTP server:

```
php -S localhost:8080
```

or

```
python3 -m http.server 8080
```

etc